# WPF Routed Event: MainWindow to UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, viewmodel

I want to have the view model of my main window inform a user control that the sorting of an `ObservableCollection` (a property of the view model) has changed via an event.

Using a shared/static method is not my solution as the main window view model should not be aware of the user control (which itself is bound to the same view model).

A list box control is using the `ObservableCollection` as a source for its Items and this scenario is simply to force `ScrollIntoView` on the list box.

I'm aware of the concept of `RoutedEvents` and tunneling which I think might be my solution but I'm not entirely sure if that's the only option. Routing in this way is a completely new concept for me.

I've looked at [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24876053/the-correct-way-to-do-a-tunneled-event) but I would need custom events presumably as opposed to existing routing events.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`CollectionChanged` event is fired by `ICollectionView`, when Items are added/removed or List is refreshed. You can make use of this event to raise your own custom event. Below code snippet demonstrates its use when Students collection of a ViewModel vm is sorted.

```
        private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ICollectionView view = (ICollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(vm.Students);
            view.CollectionChanged += view_CollectionChanged;
            view.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("Name", ListSortDirection.Ascending)); 
        }

        void view_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("view_CollectionChanged changed !");
        }
```

More can be said if you tell how you use the ViewModel's collection property in your UserControl.

Normally MainWindow and UserControls should communicate via ICommand.

[Custom Command Tutorial](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/WPFCustomCommands.aspx)

Comment: Thank you for your comment.

In this case the ObservableCollection isn't changing. I'm just using a menu on my MainWindow to sort the said ObservableCollection by using:

ListCollectionView.SortDescriptions.Add()

It's after this that I want to force my user control to use ScrollIntoView.

Comment: first of all, you should not sort the collection in MainWindow, instead UserControl itself should respond to Menu. above code can be used as is with `ListBox.ItemsSource` too : `ICollectionView view = (ICollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(myListBox.ItemsSource);`

Comment: Aside from where the collection should be sorted, I still can't see how my UserControl is aware of an event having happened in the MainWindow.

Comment: You have to use an ICommand. There can be many separate UserControls for various MainWindow:MenuItems. They will communicate using Commands. ICommand is must for MVVM.

Comment: Yes I'm familiar with ICommand and am using them already in many places but my UserControl has to react to an Event which is something different.

Comment: You can raise the event from the `CollectionChanged` event from `MainWindow`. Use original collection in your GetDefaultView() in MainWindow. Then fire the custom event.